# opening a link containing Special characters

Tags: html

I have one pdf file named SharkFinningReport10!@#$%^.pdf. Its in directory "file". I need open this file in a browser by clicking a link.
My code is below

```
<body>
    <a href="./file/SharkFinningReport10!@#$%^.pdf">click</a>
</body>
```

since pdf contains special characters I am not able to open it.

Any one knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: changing the name of the file is too hard?

Comment: try renaming the pdf and see what happens

Comment: user can put any file with any name. So its necessary to check for all condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTML escape characters to represent special characters

```
    <a href="./file/SharkFinningReport10&#33&#64&#35&#36&#37&#94.pdf">Click</a>
```

A list can be found here: [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)